# How to send iso 8601 date to Backend?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

i have a little issue.

I'm trying to send a date with a Post request to my backend but nothing goes in the back. The request is sent successfully because all the data goes to backend except the Date.

This is how need to be in the backend :

```
 "date": "2021-12-17T17:52:27.724773",
```

This is what i tried :

```
    let isoDate = "021-12-17T17:52:27.724773"
        let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        isoDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
            .withFullDate,
            .withFullTime,
            .withDashSeparatorInDate]

        if let realDate = isoDateFormatter.date(from: isoDate) {

            order.date = realDate. // order.date is of type : Date

        }
```

What needs to be done ?

Comment: I can't imagine why a backend developer would ever require such an esoteric format for a date value. I think this is such a bad design practice. Remote data should be as plain vanilla and agnostic as possible and that date value should be something like a Unix timestamp, a plain 32 or 64-bit integer. If a client or a server function needs something more fancy, then let them convert it.

Answer (score 3):

You seems to be doing this backwards, if your backend needs the date and time in a specific format you should convert a `Date` instance to a string and not the other way around.

And the `ISO8601DateFormatter` doesn't support 6 fractional digits for milliseconds so you need a standard `DateFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
```

Note that even the DateFormatter doesn't really support 6 digits, only 3, so the resulting date string will always end with "000"

The backend format doesn't contain a time zone so maybe this is assumed to be a specific one and then you need to set that as well on your formatter, for instance:

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

To use it you do something like

```
order.date = Date() // or some other Date object

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let data = try encoder.encode(order)
```

Comment: `let order = Order()
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
        let data = try? encoder.encode(order.date)
        order.date = data`
    
        
Thanks !. I tried to do something like this but is not working, i got this error  : "Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'Date?'", because data is of type data

Comment: You should encode the whole order object and not only order.date

Comment: I just assumed you want to send json to the backend hence the encoding