# Is a keyed decoding container needed for model objects?

Tags: json, swift, api, codable, decodable

Custom type posted below created to decode nested json data by the link commented out in the code. Variables set as optional were null in sample json data. Structs such as TokenDistribution were created the same way as BTCData with a CodingKey enum. Upon attempting to decode as

```
guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(BTCMarketResponse.self, from: data!)
else { 
    print("Error: Couldn't decode data into BTCMarketResponse.self") 
    return
}
```

only an error is returned. Is a keyed decoding container needed using init implementing a container(keyedBy: ) inside each struct to access the json data through the model ?

```
struct BTCMarketResponse: Codable{
    let status: Status
    let btcData: BTCData
    
    struct Status: Codable{
        var elapsed: Int
        var timestamp: Date
        
        enum StatusKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case elapsed = "elapsed"
            case timestamp = "timestamp"
        }
    }
    
    struct BTCData: Codable{
        let id: String
        let symbol: String
        let name: String
        let slug: String
        let contractAddresses: String?
        let internalTempAgoraId: String
        let isVerified: Bool
        let tagline: String
        let overview: String
        let background: String
        let technology: String
        let category: String
        let sector: String
        let tag: String
        let sFarScore: Int
        let tokenDistribution: TokenDistribution
        let tokenDetails: TokenDetails
        let organizations: [Organization]
        let people: People
        let relevantResources: [RelevantResource]
        let consesusAlgorithm: String
        
        enum BTCDataKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case id = "id"
            case symbol = "symbol"
            case name = "name"
            case slug = "slug"
            case contractAddresses = "contract_addresses"
            case internalTempAgoraId = "_internal_temp_agora_id"
            case isVerified =  "is_verified"
            case tagline = "tagline"
            case overview = "overview"
            case background = "background"
            case technology = "technology"
            case category = "category"
            case sector = "sector"
            case tag = "tag"
            case sFarScore = "sfarScore"
         
            case tokenDistribution// = "token_distribution"
         
            case tokenDetails //= "token_details"
         
            case organizations// = "organizations"
         
            case people// = "people"
         
            case relevantResources //= "relevant_resources"
         
            case consesusAlgorithm = "consensus_algorithm"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Snippet of json data added

```
{
    "status": {
        "elapsed": 1,
        "timestamp": "2021-12-23T11:34:30.671776042Z"
    },
    "data": {
        "id": "1e31218a-e44e-4285-820c-8282ee222035",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "contract_addresses": null,
        "_internal_temp_agora_id": "9793eae6-f374-46b4-8764-c2d224429791",
        "is_verified": false,
        "tagline": "A peer-to-peer electronic cash system",
        "overview": "Bitcoin is the first \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/distributed-systems\"\u003edistributed consensus-based\u003c/a\u003e, censorship-resistant, permissionless, peer-to-peer payment settlement network with a provably scarce, programmable, native currency. Bitcoin (BTC), the native asset of the Bitcoin blockchain, is the world's first digital currency without a central bank or administrator. The Bitcoin network is an emergent decentralized monetary institution that exists through the interplay between \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/node\"\u003efull nodes\u003c/a\u003e, \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/mining\"\u003eminers\u003c/a\u003e, and developers. It is set by a social contract that is created and opted into by the users of the network and hardened through \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/c/resource/game-theory\"\u003egame theory\u003c/a\u003e and \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/cryptography\"\u003ecryptography\u003c/a\u003e. Bitcoin is the first, oldest, and largest cryptocurrency in the world.",
        "background": "\nPre-history\nBitcoin borrows from nearly three decades of research by academics, cypherpunk practitioners, and hobbyists who tried to create similar payment protocols. Some of the most prominent projects that preceded Bitcoin include: Digicash, b-money, Hashcash, e-gold, and Bit Gold. Bitcoin is often associated with Austrian economic theories, anarcho-capitalist principles, and general libertarian politicking by virtue of the exclusive developer community to whom Nakamoto first released their white paper, certain protocol design characteristics, and the political affiliations of early Bitcoin investors. \n\nConception to Launch\nOn October 31, 2008, at the peak of the Global Financial Crisis, just six weeks after the infamous investment bank, Lehman Brothers, declared bankruptcy, the pseudonymous \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/satoshi-nakamoto\"\u003eSatoshi Nakamoto\u003c/a\u003e released the Bitcoin whitepaper to the cryptography mailing list. Titled \"Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System\", the whitepaper proposed a new electronic cash system that would allow fully peer-to-peer online payments without reliance on trusted third parties. Soon after the release of the whitepaper, Satoshi implemented the Bitcoin software as open-source code. On 3 January 2009, the Bitcoin network came into existence with Satoshi mining the genesis block of Bitcoin, which included a now-famous \"The Times\" headline in the \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/coinbase-transaction\"\u003ecoinbase\u003c/a\u003e both to prove the network’s fair launch and to make a political statement about the global financial system. The event marked the birth of the world's first non-sovereign, decentralized, digital money.\n\nPost Launch\n\u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/hal-finney\"\u003eHal Finney\u003c/a\u003e, who invented the first reusable proof-of-work system (RPoW) in 2004, received the first Bitcoin transaction (10 bitcoins) on January 12, 2009. In 2010, the first known commercial transaction using bitcoin occurred when programmer \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/laszlo-hanyecz\"\u003eLaszlo Hanyecz\u003c/a\u003e bought two Papa John's pizzas for 10,000 bitcoins. \n\nIn August 2010, a major vulnerability in the Bitcoin protocol was spotted and exploited in the Bitcoin network, allowing users to create an infinite amount of bitcoins. The transactions exploiting the vulnerability were quickly spotted and erased for the Bitcoin blockchain, with the vulnerability being patched in a network upgrade of the Bitcoin protocol. This was the only major security flaw found and exploited in Bitcoin's history.\n\nIn December 2010, amidst rising publicity from Bitcoin's use in financing Wikileaks, Satoshi Nakamoto, disappeared from involvement with Bitcoin. It is unknown why Satoshi disappeared from the project, although some believe Satoshi, cognizant of past struggles to launch a digital currency, recognized that a leader of the Bitcoin project could be a central point of failure. It is estimated that Nakamoto had mined about one million bitcoins before disappearing in 2010 when he handed the network alert key and control of the code repository over to \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/gavin-andresen\"\u003eGavin Andresen\u003c/a\u003e.\n\nSilk Road \u0026 Mt. Gox\nOne of the most iconic early use cases for Bitcoin was the Silk Road. Launched in early 2011, the Silk Road was a darknet marketplace that allowed users to buy and sell a wide variety of goods including, most notably, illegal drugs. Underpinning the Silk Road was the Tor network, which allowed users to browse the Silk Road anonymously and securely without potential traffic monitoring, and Bitcoin which provided a censorship-resistant payment rail for pseudonymous transactions. Over the course of its life, it is estimated that the Silk Road facilitated more than $1.2 billion in transactions, collecting over $80 million in sales commissions, leveraging the Bitcoin network as its payment rail. The site was shut down in 2013 when the FBI took advantage of the Silk Road’s centralized infrastructure, arresting founder \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/ross-ulbricht\"\u003eRoss Ulbricht\u003c/a\u003e, and shuttering the site.\n\nFounded by \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/jed-mccaleb\"\u003eJed McCaleb\u003c/a\u003e in July 2010, and led by \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/mark-karpeles\"\u003eMark Karpeles\u003c/a\u003e until it collapsed, \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/organization/mtgox\"\u003eMt. Gox\u003c/a\u003e was one of the earliest Bitcoin exchanges in the world. Based in Tokyo, Japan, the exchange would go on to handle over 70% of all bitcoin (BTC) transactions worldwide at its peak. Known for its chronic security issues, Mt. Gox was infamously hacked in 2014, losing 850,000 bitcoins worth about $450 million at the time. The hack sent the price of Bitcoin, which was in the midst of one of its first major price bubbles, plummeting. Bitcoin would sink into a bear market with prices not recovering until the 2017 bull run.\n\n2017 Bubble \u0026 Bitcoin Cash Hard Fork\nThe 2017 price bubble was a watershed moment for Bitcoin. The price of Bitcoin rose more than 1900% from just under $1,000 at the beginning of the year to near $20,000 at its peak in December. At its peak, Bitcoin's market capitalization eclipsed $325 billion. Along with the proliferation of Initial Coin Offerings, powered by Ethereum, Bitcoin's incredible 2017 run propelled cryptocurrency into mainstream consciousness, among the most discussed phenomena of 2017.\n\nAlso notable in 2017, Bitcoin experienced its \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/article/bitcoin-cash-hard-fork\"\u003emost contentious fork to date\u003c/a\u003e. Amidst rising transaction fees on Bitcoin and increasingly divergent views on scaling Bitcoin, an agreement was reached amongst prominent Bitcoin stakeholders in what is now known as the \"New York Agreement\". The agreement was to support a set of network upgrades called SegWit2x. The proposal was backed by over 80% of Bitcoin's hash rate. However, despite the desires of miners, users wanted to activate \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/article/segregated-witness\"\u003eSegWit\u003c/a\u003e without the 2MB block size increase, the philosophy underpinning this decision being that the users controlled the network, not miners and Bitcoin businesses. Subsequently, they set a date (August 1, 2017) where Bitcoin would soft fork to support SegWit and keep the 1MB block size. Enough nodes signaled support for it that they forced miners to accept or have their blocks rejected by the network. A faction of the bigger blocks camp, rejected SegWit altogether, citing frustrations with the prioritization of SegWit over bigger blocks, and on August 1, 2017, they launched a hard fork of Bitcoin called Bitcoin Cash, with 8MB block limits. These events marked, one end, a landmark demonstration of power by the users of the Bitcoin network, and on the other end, the first great schism within the Bitcoin community.\n\n2018 - 2019\nAfter peaking in December 2017, Bitcoin, along with the rest of the cryptocurrency market in January 2018, crashed, sending the cryptocurrency market into its latest bear market. Since then Bitcoin has dropped as low as $3,200, more than 80% below its ATH. However, while prices have yet to recover to 2017 highs, the institutionalization of Bitcoin has picked up significantly. Traditional Wall Street institutions including Chicago Mercantile Exchange, Intercontinental Exchange, and Fidelity have all launched cryptocurrency offerings, opening up the market to institutional investors. There are now several regulated exchanges and custodians. Furthermore, regulatory clarity around Bitcoin has improved dramatically with SEC Chairman, Jay Clayton, revealing at a Congressional hearing in February 2018, that the SEC does not consider Bitcoin to be a security.\n\nSince it reached its cycle low in February 2019, Bitcoin's price has recovered considerably, rising as high as $13,000 in June. With the recent announcements of Facebook's Libra project and China's Central Bank digital currency, governments and multinational corporations around the world have begun to look at cryptocurrencies more seriously. American officials are debating a digital dollar and lawmakers around the world are considering the central bank digital currency (CBDC) options. Furthermore, there have been numerous cryptocurrency-related hearings since Libra was announced. China has recently \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/article/china-blockchain-madness\"\u003eannounced\u003c/a\u003e blockchain was a revolutionary technology and that it would make blockchain technology a strategic imperative for the country. Bitcoin's price rose more than 40% after the announcement, its highest intraday movement since 2011.\n\n2020 - 2021\nBitcoin traded sideways into 2020, but the onset of the novel Coronavirus (COVID-19) Pandemic saw world markets take the biggest dips since at least the 2007-08 Mortgage Crisis. Bitcoin did not escape the dip – in less than 48 hours it lost half of its value, going below $4,000 for the first time since March of 2019. Luckily for bitcoiners, bitcoin rebounded, returning to its pre-pandemic price in less than a month.\n\nBitcoin’s ascent recovery out of the March turmoil drew wider media and institutional attention and lent credibility to its store of value narrative. Although it remained around $10,000 throughout Ethereum’s firey \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/article/a-data-driven-look-at-the-end-of-defi-s-summer\"\u003eDeFi summer\u003c/a\u003e, bitcoin would start to trend upwards into the fall and by early November bitcoin hit $14,000. Whether it was unprecedented levels of money printing by the Federal Reserve, its V-shaped recovery in April, or direct stimulus payments to millions of Americans, it was clear bitcoin wasn’t done at $14,000 as it crossed $20,000 for the first time ever on December 16, 2020. Two weeks later it hit $28,000. Then, on January 8, 2021, bitcoin set a new all-time high of $41,429.38. Since hitting $41,000 bitcoin has mostly drifted in the $30,000.\n\nBitcoin’s price wasn’t the only thing rapidly accelerating in 2020. Institutional adoption skyrocketed. Led by Paul Tudor Jones of Microstrategy (  $1 billion), institutions joined the bitcoin world en masse. From insurance companies like MassMutual ($100 million) to investment firms like Ruffer ($744 million) new groups \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/article/the-potential-impact-of-increased-capital-allocation-to-bitcoin\"\u003econtinue\u003c/a\u003e to adopt bitcoin. And institutions aren’t alone – entrepreneurs like Elon Musk and politicians like Miami Mayor Francis Suarez have increasingly promoted bitcoin. Even athletes have joined the space, as NFL player Russell Okung partnered with Bitcoin Lightning Company \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/organization/zap\"\u003eZap\u003c/a\u003e to become the first professional sports player ever to be paid in bitcoin\n\n",
        "technology": "\"Bitcoin\" is a label used for a protocol and a currency.\n\nBitcoin, the currency, is bits of data usable outside the limitations of the protocol using second-layer solutions like \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/lightning-network\"\u003eLightning Network\u003c/a\u003e payment channels. \n\nBitcoin, the protocol, is a distributed, time-stamped ledger of \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/utxo\"\u003eunspent transaction output\u003c/a\u003e (UTXO) transfers stored in an append-only chain of 1MB data blocks. A network of mining and economic \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/node\"\u003enodes\u003c/a\u003e maintains this ledger by validating, propagating, and fighting to include \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/resource/mempool\"\u003emempool\u003c/a\u003e transactions in new blocks. Economic nodes (aka \"full nodes\") receive transactions from other network participants, validate them against network consensus rules and double-spend vectors, and propagate the transactions to other full nodes that also validate and propagate. Valid transactions are sent to the network's mempool waiting for mining nodes to confirm them via inclusion in the next block.\n\nMining nodes work to empty the mempool usually in a highest-to-lowest fee order by picking transactions to include in the next block and racing against each other to generate a hash less than the target number set by Bitcoin's difficulty adjustment algorithm. Bitcoin uses a Proof-of-Work (PoW) consensus mechanism to establish the chain of blocks with the most accumulated “work” (a.k.a., energy spent on solved hashes) as the valid chain. Other network peers can cheaply verify the chain’s work.\n\nMining difficulty regularly adjusts to maintain Bitcoin's average ten-minute block schedule. Mining nodes add new blocks to whatever chain has the largest accumulated proof of work maintained by a network of economic nodes with downloaded copies of the same chain.\n\nLearn More:\nBitcoin Developer's Guide\nMastering Bitcoin",
        "category": "Payments",
        "sector": "Currencies",
        "tag": "",
        "sfarScore": 1,
        "token_distribution": {
            "sale_start": null,
            "sale_end": null,
            "initial_distribution": 0,
            "current_supply": null,
            "max_supply": 20999999.9769,
            "description": "Satoshi Nakamoto created the first bitcoins on January 3, 2009, by mining the genesis block. The genesis block mining reward (50 BTC) is unspendable due to the original client's block database and transaction database configuration. The coinbase of the first block included the following text:\n  \"The Times 03/Jan/2009 Chancellor on brink of second bailout for banks\"\n\nThis text has been interpreted both as a proof that the block was created on January 3, 2009, as well as a comment on fractional-reserve banking. \u003ca href=\"https://messari.io/person/hal-finney\"\u003eHal Finney\u003c/a\u003e received the first bitcoin transaction on January 12, 2009. Finney had downloaded the bitcoin software when it was first released and was known the be the creator of RPoW, the first reusable proof-of-work system, in 2004."
        },
```

Comment: Can you show an example/snippet of the JSON that you are trying to decode?

Comment: The full json data available at https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/bitcoin/profile, a snippet of the json data also added. Thank you

Comment: Don't use `try?` and print a hard coded error, use `try` and print the actual error using `do {} catch {}`. (I wonder how many times this needs to be repeated?).

Comment: NEVER USE `try?` unless your able to debug it yourself (which means some experience). Use a proper `do { try } catch {}` instead.

Comment: Thank you. New to Swift just yet. The issue is as follows: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "status", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "timestamp", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.", underlyingError: nil)) although I have set decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

Comment: That date is not ISO 8601, so you need a custom formatter. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402533/9223839) but with a 'Z' at the end

Comment: From JSON: `"timestamp": "2021-12-23T11:34:30.671776042Z"` Is that `.iso8601`? I don't think with that much fractional seconds numbers. You need to use a custom DateFormatter (and dateFormat).

Comment: iso8601 issue SOLVED: Thank you for the responses. Adding the following extension ``` extension DateFormatter {
    static let fullISO8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}  ```  and setting decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.fullISO8601)

Comment: How could the following difference between "btcData" and \"btcData"\ be approached ? keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "btcData", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"btcData\", intValue: nil) (\"btcData\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: You need a CodingKey enum for your top struct BTCMarketResponse as well

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The enum was present, however the error persisted. Setting the variables in the top struct as optional helped and now the response for decodedData.status is Status(elapsed: Optional(4), timestamp: 2021-12-25 17:25:51 +0000). Although decodedData.btcData returns nil, I can count this issue solved. Thank you !!